# Natural solutions to $a+b^2+c^4+b^4c^4=x+y^2+z^4+y^4z^4$, with $(a,b,c)\neq(x,y,z)$ and at least one of $a$, $b$, $c$, and one of $x$, $y$, $z$ is $0$

Tags: number-theory

> How many solutions are there for this equation on $\Bbb N$
> $$a+b^2+c^4+b^4c^4=x+y^2+z^4+y^4z^4$$
> with $(a,b,c)\neq(x,y,z)$ and at least one of $a,b,c$ and one of $x,y,z$ is equal to zero?

**Edit**: what if the equation be this: $a+3b^2+5c^4+7b^4c^4=x+3y^2+5z^4+7y^4z^4$

**Edit 2**: how could we apply Fermat's last theorem for correction of this function $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ given by $f(x,y,z)=x+3y^2+5z^4+7y^4z^4$ with this property:
there's no natural solution for the equation $$a+3b^2+5c^4+7b^4c^4=x+3y^2+5z^4+7y^4z^4$$ with $(a,b,c)\neq(x,y,z)$ and at least one of $a,b,c$ and one of $x,y,z$ is equal to zero.

I need it to make a total order relation on a sphere $S^2$.

**the philosophy** is *Fermat's last theorem* $\times$ *stock mathematics*

**in other words** Mathematicians usually accustom to think *induction axiom* like or the same $n=(n-1)+1$ like but another outlook is *Fermat's last theorem* like or the same $a^2+b^2=c^2$ like that I predict it for making an Euclidean domain on a sphere $S^2$ or another one is *axiom of choice* like that my $B$ theory & $S$ theory are two samples for.

**why theory**: if we can apply *Fermat's last theorem* for correction of or improving the function mentioned above in which the conditions must be fixed and don't be changed then for the first time we will succeed to think *Fermat's last theorem* like maybe the result is a series or something else but I don't know what it is.

Thanks,
[Alireza Badali Sarebangholi](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/User:Musictheory2math)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Infinitely many. Just take $c=z=0$ and infinitely many numbers can be written as $b^2-y^2$. (You should really include your efforts, otherwise it's rude to demand answers like @md2perpe said).

Comment: I am not going to download a RAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{Case\ of\ a=0\ and\ x=0}:$

$$b^2+c^4+b^4c^4=y^2+z^4+y^4z^4\tag{1}$$

Let $bc=yz$, then we get

$$b^2+c^4=y^2+z^4\tag{2}$$

Thus, we have to find the integer solutions of equation $(2)$ with $bc=yz.$

Let $b=p(t+f), c=q(t-f), y=p(t-f), z=q(t+f)$, then we get
$$t = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2p^2-4q^4f^2}}{q^2}$$
Hence $2p^2-4q^4f^2$ must be square number and let $q=1.$

We get the parametric solution of $v^2=2p^2-4f^2$ as follows.

$(v,f,p)=(4k^2-8k+2, 2k^2-8k+7, 4k^2-12k+10)$
$k$ is arbitrary.

Let $k = \frac{\large{m}}{\large{n}}$ with m,n are integers, hence we get the parametric solution.
$(b,c,y,z)=(8(5n^2+2m^2-6mn)(2n-m)(n-m), (-6n+4m)n, 4(5n^2+2m^2-6mn)(3n-2m)n, 4(2n-m)(n-m))$

Hence equation $(1)$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions.

```
           [ m,n ] [   b,   c ] [   y,  z  ]
           [ 3, 1],[   20,   3],[   15,   4]
           [ 4, 1],[  156,   5],[   65,  12]
           [ 7, 2],[  255,   8],[  136,  15]
           [ 5, 1],[  600,   7],[  175,  24]
           [ 1, 4],[  609,  20],[  580,  21]
           [ 9, 2],[ 1295,  12],[  444,  35]
           [ 6, 1],[ 1640,   9],[  369,  40]
           [10, 3],[ 3640,  33],[ 2145,  56]
           [ 7, 1],[ 3660,  11],[  671,  60]
           [ 1, 6],[ 4015,  48],[ 3504,  55]
           [ 1, 5],[ 6984,  65],[ 6305,  72]
           [ 8, 1],[ 7140,  13],[ 1105,  84]
           [ 9, 1],[12656,  15],[ 1695, 112]
           [ 1, 8],[14385,  88],[12056, 105]
           [ 2, 7],[20280, 119],[20111, 120]
           [10, 1],[20880,  17],[ 2465, 144]
           [ 1, 7],[31980, 133],[27265, 156]
           [ 1,10],[37791, 140],[30940, 171]
           [ 1, 9],[96016, 225],[79425, 272]
           [ 2, 9],[68320, 207],[63135, 224]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127293/discussion-on-answer-by-tomita-natural-solutions-to-ab2c4b4c4xy2z4).

Comment: sorry I couldn't sort my theory.

Answer (score 0):

Equation given by "OP" is:

$a+b^2+c^4+b^4c^4=x+y^2+z^4+y^4z^4$

Above has numerical solution:

$(a,b,c)=(3919,7,2)$

$(x,y,z)=(32359,5,2)$

Comment: at least one of $a,b,c$ and one of $x,y,z$ must be equal to zero.

Comment: is the OP your friend?